# TempData still available after subsequent http requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

My textbook says that "TempData gets destroyed immediately after it’s used in subsequent HTTP request", so I write a simple test to verify

below is my code:

```
// SimpleForm.cshtml is just a simple view that uses a form to send post request to ReceiveForm action method
//Result.cshtml is just a simple view that products an output

public class HomeController : Controller
{
   public ViewResult Index() => View("SimpleForm");

   [HttpPost]
   public RedirectToActionResult ReceiveForm(string name, string city)
   {
      TempData["name"] = name;
      TempData["city"] = city;
      return RedirectToAction(nameof(Transfer));
   }

   public RedirectToActionResult Transfer()
   {
       string name = TempData["name"] as string;
       string city = TempData["city"] as string;
       return RedirectToAction(nameof(Data));
   }

   public ViewResult Data()
   {
      string name = TempData["name"] as string;
      string city = TempData["city"] as string;
      return View("Result", $"{name} lives in {city}");
   } 
}
```

so when the application runs, it goes to Index() action method first, I fill up the form with name and city and press submit button, then it goes to ReceiveForm() action method, which setup `TempData` and redirect to Transfer() action method.

In the Transfer() action method, I read TempData, so TempData should get destroyed and unavailable to read in the next http request according to the textbook.

But in the Data(), I find that I can still read TempData, see the screenshot below:

[image]

and I checked the chrome dev tool, there was one post request and two get requests, which is all good and correct. **so when does TempData actually get destroyed ?**

additional code:

SimpleForm.cshtml:

```
@{ Layout = null; }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Controllers and Actions</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" asp-href-include="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/*.min.css" />
</head>
<body class="m-1 p-1">
    <form method="post" asp-action="ReceiveForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="name" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">City:</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="city" />
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary center-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Result.cshtml:

```
@model string
@{ Layout = null; }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Controllers and Actions</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" asp-href-include="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/*.min.css" />
</head>
<body class="m-1 p-1">
    Model Data: @Model
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, i tried the same thing. The tempdata didn't reach the Data Method. Can you provide additional details like which version of .net core or framework you are using.

Comment: Hello, Can u Change RedirectToAction  to Redirect and specify the url as string? 
I thing the temp data is still traped because its redirecting at the same context try the Redirect method.

Comment: I used the auto generated code and modified it accordingly. I will copy your exact code and see. Please post the code for yoru simple form

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada well, I haven't tried that, but RedirectToAction  triggers get request, so they should be the different context , plus a user tried my code and got a different result from mine

Comment: I copied and pasted yoru exact code for controller and views. It still didn't get to the data method. I am uisng .net core 2.2. Not sure what's going on. You can raise an issue on Github and have Microsoft look into it

Answer (score 1):

For your scenario, this is caused by `RedirectToActionResult`. For `RedirectToActionResult`, which is `IKeepTempDataResult`.

```
public class RedirectToActionResult : ActionResult, IKeepTempDataResult
```

[SaveTempDataFilter](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/84da613d2c03b6f1c0fa3c01828923ec3415d525/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/Filters/SaveTempDataFilter.cs#L110) is filter that saves temp data. It will call `SaveTempData`.

```
private static void SaveTempData(
    IActionResult result,
    ITempDataDictionaryFactory factory,
    IList<IFilterMetadata> filters,
    HttpContext httpContext)
{
    var tempData = factory.GetTempData(httpContext);

    for (var i = 0; i < filters.Count; i++)
    {
        if (filters[i] is ISaveTempDataCallback callback)
        {
            callback.OnTempDataSaving(tempData);
        }
    }

    if (result is IKeepTempDataResult)
    {
        tempData.Keep();
    }

    tempData.Save();
}
```

For `SaveTempData`, it will check whether `IActionResult result` is `IKeepTempDataResult`. If it is, it will keep the tempData.

If you want to avoid keep `tempData` between request, you could change `RedirectToAction` to `LocalRedirect` like

```
public IActionResult Transfer()
{
    string name = TempData["name"] as string;
    string city = TempData["city"] as string;
    return LocalRedirect("~/Home/Data");
    //return RedirectToAction(nameof(Data));
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer. I am sure it's also the correct answer. i didn't test it myself but it seems to be the correct one. +1